# I am trying to create and implement a function that identifies outliers in datasets in Python using the numpy module, keep getting 'ValueError'

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, dataset

I am attempting to create an 'Outlier' function that detects outliers in data sets. I am then trying to call the function into a for loop but it keeps giving me a `ValueError`. I have a brief understanding of why the error occurs. It's because numpy doesn't let you set arrays as Booleans (Please correct me if I'm wrong). I was just wondering if there was a way around this, and how would I implement the `a.any()`, `a.all()` suggestions the error is giving me.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def Outlier(a, IQR, Q1, Q3):
    if a < Q1 - 1.5 * IQR or a > Q3 + 1.5 * IQR:    
        outlier = True
    else:
        outlier = False        
    return(outlier)


data_clean = []

Q1 = np.percentile(data, 25)
Q3 = np.percentile(data, 75)

print("Q1 = {:,.2f}".format(Q1)) 
print("Q3 = {:,.2f}".format(Q3)) 

n= len(data)

for i in range(n): 
    outlier[i] = Outlier(data, IQR, Q1, Q3) # Error

    if outlier[i] == False : # Error
        data_clean.append(data[i])
    else:
        print("value removed (outlier) = {:,.2f}".format(data[i]))

data_clean = np.asarray(data_clean)
n = len(data_clean) 
print("n = {:.0f}".format(n)) 

print("data_clean = {}".format(data_clean))
```

Full error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f686bd0a0718> in <module>

---> 19     outlier[i] = Outlier(data, IQR, Q1, Q3)
---> 20     if outlier[i] == False :            #check for outlier

<ipython-input-29-1f034e2a09b6> in Outlier(a, IQR, Q1, Q3)
3 def Outlier(a, IQR, Q1, Q3):
4
---> 5     if a < Q1 - 1.5 * IQR or a > Q3 + 1.5 * IQR:
6
7              outlier = True
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks in advance.
Just to clarify the code above is meant to check for outliers in a dataset and then add the non-outliers to a `data_clean` list, leaving the dataset with no outliers.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: you are passing the whole `data` to your Outlier function , you should pass only `data[i]`

Answer (score 2):

I think that, rather than iterating, you could do everything inside the function without looping:

```
import numpy as np

def detect_outliers(arr, pct_bounds=(75, 25), mulitplier=1.5):
    upper, lower = np.percentile(arr, pct_bounds)
    spread = upper - lower
    # Create a mask where the data are more than or less than 1.5 * IQR from the median
    mask = (arr < (np.median(arr) - (multiplier * spread))) | (arr > (np.median(arr) + (multiplier * spread)))
    outliers = arr[mask]
    # Invert mask
    new_array = arr[~mask]
    return outliers, new_array

test_data = np.random.normal(size=100)
outliers, data = detect_outliers(test_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will definitely try this.