# Trying to create a program that adds outliers of a data set to a new list (So I can identify how many outliers are in a dataset)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dataset, outliers

I am attempting to create a program that generates a data set based on numbers you give it and then plots a histogram based on the data set. I need to see the exact number of outliers in the data set, I am trying to do this by creating a 'clean' list with all of the non-outliers and and then leaving the original data set array with only outliers. However, when I try to do this both arrays stay exactly the same. Not isolating outliers at all. (It's like there are no outliers in the data)
(All I need to achieve with this program is seeing the bin_count_1, bin_count_2 and the amount of outliers in the data set)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv

data_seed = 1700
data_mean = 175
data_size = 1123
data_bin_num = 41

data_std = 7

np.random.seed(data_seed)
data_set = np.random.normal(data_mean, data_std, size = data_size)

data_bin_count, data_value, patches = plt.hist(data_set, facecolor='blue', bins = 41)

plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.axis([np.amin(data_set), np.amax(data_set), 0, 1.05*np.amax(data_bin_count)])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

bin_count_1 = data_bin_count[data_bin_num // 4]
bin_count_2 = data_bin_count[data_bin_num // 2]
print(bin_count_1, bin_count_2)
       
def Outlier(a, IQR, Q1, Q3):
    
    if a < Q1 - 1.5 * IQR or a > Q3 + 1.5 * IQR:
    
        outlier = True
    else:
        outlier = False
        
    return(outlier)

data_clean = []
outlier_set = []

Q1 = np.percentile(data_set, 25) 
Q3 = np.percentile(data_set, 75)
IQR = max(data_set) - min(data_set) 
IQRround = round(IQR, 2) 

print("Q1 = {:,.2f}".format(Q1)) 
print("Q3 = {:,.2f}".format(Q3))
print(f"IQR = {IQRround}") 

n= len(data_set)

for i in range(n):        
    
    outlier = Outlier(data_set[i], IQR, Q1, Q3)

    if outlier == False :            
        data_clean.append(data_set[i])
    else:
        print("value removed (outlier) = {:,.2f}".format(data_set[i])) 
        
data_clean = np.asarray(data_clean) 

n = len(data_clean) 
print("n = {:.0f}".format(n)) 

print("data_clean = {}".format(data_clean))
print(f"data_set = {data_set}") 

data_outlier_count = len(data_set)
print(data_outlier_count)
```

Outlier detection function:

```
def Outlier(a, IQR, Q1, Q3):
    
    if a < Q1 - 1.5 * IQR or a > Q3 + 1.5 * IQR:
    
        outlier = True
    else:
        outlier = False
        
    return(outlier)
```

Error:
Program is not detecting outliers from a data set (All I need to know is the bin_count_1, bin_count_2 and the amount of outliers in the data.

Things I have already tried:
Removing the outliers to a completely separate list.
Subtracting 'data_set' and 'data_clean' it = 0

It is like the detection function isn't working at all, the program doesn't know what an outlier is and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to create and implement a function that identifies outliers in datasets in Python using the numpy module, keep getting 'ValueError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425558/i-am-trying-to-create-and-implement-a-function-that-identifies-outliers-in-datas)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer. For some reason I have put the IQR to equal the max number of the data set - the min number.
It should be IQR = Q3 - Q1, the outliers show up now.